# Algebraic equation involving both logarithm and exponential terms

Tags: approximation, inverse-function

Consider the following equation:

$$
y = \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{x}} + \frac{1}{1+\log(x)}
$$

Is it possible to solve for $x$ analytically (as a function of $y$)? I guess this may not be possible, or is it?

Anyway, assuming this is not possible, then let us assume that $y$ is real, i.e., exclude the domain range (of $x$) that causes $y$ to have imaginary parts.

Let us further suppose that we know that ($x_1$,$y_1$) belong to the curve of this equation. My question is: is there a way to approximate $x_2$ for a given $y_2$ such that $\lvert y_1-y_2 \rvert < \delta$, where $\delta$ is a very small real number?

Comment: As far as I know there's no closed form for the inverse; a series expansion could perhaps do this for you though. You simply want to approximate the function to arbitrary precision, and that is very possible

Comment: Thanks Brevan, but what I really need is to approximate the inverse of the function. Is there a way to approximate the perturbation in $x$ given the details of the perturbation in $y$?

Comment: yes,  absolutely! It just depends on how accurate you want to be. What you are asking for is equivalent to approximating the inverse function within a small interval $\delta$. There are a number of ways to do this, it just all depends on how complex you want to go (which depends on how accurate you want to be)!

Comment: in case you misunderstood me,  I was referring to the the inverse function in my first comment. There are some Summation inversion theorems that might help, or we could take Taylor series to a few terms, or so forth

Comment: What is the context of this problem?

Comment: Thanks Breven. The context is the electrical resistance of a phase change material. And the reason I'm trying to find $x$ is that the resistance $y$ drifts with time and $x$ has to be updated to balance the model. Would it be possible to advise the names of those summation inversion theorems so I can look them up, please?

Comment: I could, but they will probably only converge within a certain interval. What interval are the x values in?

Comment: approximating e^x is not hard... It's really the logarithm that is going to throw the curve ball here. Moreover, it really depends on where you want to approximate the function. For example, around $x=0$ we have that $y \approx \frac{1}{1+\log x }+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: That approximation is within $0.5$ precision for all $x\leq 10$ or so, and is thus decent for small values. For values of $x$ greater than that I recommend $y\approx \frac 1x + \frac 15$, which has a maximum error less than $0.5$ and is a good deal closer than that for all reasonably small values of $x$. Both of those functions should be invertible easily; however, if you want more precision you could either work out better functions (which is hit or miss as far as increasing accuracy and being possible goes) or you could use numerical estimation. Both of these functions have easily...

Comment: .... calculated derivatives, which can yield some nicely convergent and iterative processes if you are willing to use a computer. If you're going for precision, that's your best bet probably!

Comment: Thank you very much Brevan. That is really very helpful.

Comment: no problem,  glad I could help out! I'll try to find time to post a formal answer later that goes into more detail... I've been pretty busy recently, and writing MathJax on a mobile device is a nightmare for more than $1$ or $2$ lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm fairly certain that there is no way to invert your function exactly. There are a number of ways to get around this, and I will investigate a few over the course of this answer. We will start with the most naive way, which is probably utilizing the McLaurin Expansion. For all $x<10$ we have that your function is roughly approximated by (correct to at least the integer part)
$$y\approx\frac{1}{1+\log(x)} + \frac 12 \implies x\approx\frac{\log(y)+1}{2\log(y)+2}$$
This becomes increasingly accurate as we approach zero, and does so quite rapidly. However, as we quickly go further away we find that $y$ is **much** better approximated by
$$y\sim\frac{1}{1+\log(x)} \implies x\sim e^{\frac{1}{y}-1}$$
In fact, this is better for **all** $x>1.0986$ (approximately), and has an error that decays to $4.663\times10^{-15}$ at a mere value of $x=\mathbf{33}$, which continues to decrease exponentially to $0$. This is due to the rapid growth of the exponential function, in contrast the extremely slow growth of the logarithmic function. As such, if your values of $x$ are anything greater than $1$ this is absolutely the way to go.
  $$$$

**Addendum**

If you really desire a function that works decently and is a rational function then I recommend using Pade Approximations. They are based on Taylor series, but work decently well outside of the Taylor series' radius of convergence. For example, the error in the approximation
$$\log(x)\approx\frac{-3+3x^2}{1+4x^2+x}$$
increases roughly by a value of $2$ for every $10\times$ increase in $x$. For example, the error at $x=10^{14}$ is $29.236$, and the error at $x=10^{15}$ is $31.539$. The error is $0$ in the neighborhood of $x=1$, and is fairly large for low values of $x$ (due to the short interval between powers of $10$). If this is an issue you could always calculate a higher order Pade Approximation... the Mathematica code is

> PadeApproximant$[f,{x,x_0,n}]$

where $f$ is the function, $x$ is the variable, $x_0$ is the point around which to approximate, and $n$ is the order of the approximation (highest power of $x$). Increasing $n$ will increase the accuracy, and you can always construct a Pade Approximation around a given point. However, this rapidly gets ugly, being too long to show accurately in MathJax. If this expression is so ugly, why do I mention it? Because a Pade Approximatin could augment the great approximation provided near the top of the post. This is absolutely true if you wish to approximate for values around $1$. Don't calculate the function's Pade Approximation as a whole though as I just did.... Your sanity will decrease rapidly. Instead, approximate $\log(x)$ using a Pade Approximation and approximate $e^x$ using a Taylor series, and then solve for $x$. If you drop unneeded terms this should provide a great approximation that can be solved exactly. The Taylor and Pade expressions can both be made fourth order and have $x$ solved for exactly, although a second order is WAY easier to work with.

Of course, this is likely a lot of overkill. For basically anything practical greater than $10$ or so the second approximation near the top will work perfectly fine, with the error already being on the order of $10^{-5}$, likely within most measurement precision. If all this doesn't do it for you, there are other techniques keeping track of the error in a Taylor or Pade approximation to get within $\delta$ of a value, but this will get really complicated and prone to impossibility really quickly based on restrictions imposed.

Comment: Many thanks Brevan for this detailed answer. Just a suggestion: Citing/listing your references can be very helpful for people seeking more information about this subject (like you know who :).

Comment: @user8420488483439 I actually didn't reference anything for this answer... I just knew all this prior, and the calculations were worked out by hand (excluding a few with Mathematica, but they really bogged down my first version of the post. I merely mention that its "ugly" now). What aspect of this do you want references to? What level of mathematical knowledge do you have? I can definitely get you some good references for whatever you need! I just need to know what you know already and what you are most interested in learning more about, so I can get understandable and interesting references.